# Using UdpClient, how do you retry UdpClient.Connect() until it succeeds?

Tags: c#, udpclient

My client/server programs work well with each other, but only when the server is up and running before my client starts. If the client fails to connect on the first try, I can't get it to try again.

Here's my Client's `connect` method.

```
public void connect()
    {          
        IPAddress server_address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPEndPoint server_ip = new IPEndPoint(server_address, 5685);
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        bool connected = false;
        while (!connected)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IN CONNECTED");
                udp_client.Connect(server_ip);
                byte[] send_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("INIT");
                udp_client.Send(send_data, send_data.Length);
                byte[] received_bytes = udp_client.Receive(ref server_ip);
                string received_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received_bytes);
                if (received_data == "INIT")
                {
                    connected = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("RECEIVED INIT");
                    listen(server_ip);
                }

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I was hoping to see is the `udp_client.Connect(server_ip)` to loop until I received that "INIT" message from the server.

As it currently stands, there is no loop. It seems to get stuck on `udp_client.Receive(ref server_ip)`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a loop to me -- no way out unless connected = true. What is happening? Debug and find out why connected is being set to true

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the loop doesn't happen. It either connects or it doesn't and the program has to be restarted. When debugging, the loop hangs on `udp_client.Receive()`.

Comment: Then receive is a blocking call and it will wait forever until it gets something. That's not a hang. Put the method in a separate thread and it'll just wait until it gets a response and then continue.

Comment: But how do I continue looping if receive is a blocking call and also the only way to confirm a connection?

Comment: You don't need to loop - receive() just waits until there is a connection to proceed. You can move it to a background thread and have it set a bool with class scope to true when it connects. Test against that bool for connection status

Comment: if your control flow has hit `Receive` then it means it has connected to the server and is waiting for a message. you also need `if(!connected)udp_client.Connect(server_ip);` connect only if not already connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pseudoCode - you will have to move somethings to class scope to allow future send/receives (which you'd do using a different method). This is only designed to show you how to connect when the connection blocks:

```
bool isClientConnected = false;
var connector = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

public void connectToUDP(){
    connector.DoWork+= connect;
    connector.RunWorkerAsync();
} 

 private void connect(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{          
    IPAddress server_address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    IPEndPoint server_ip = new IPEndPoint(server_address, 5685);
    Console.WriteLine("2");

                try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for server...");
            udp_client.Connect(server_ip);
            byte[] send_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("INIT");
            udp_client.Send(send_data, send_data.Length);
            byte[] received_bytes = udp_client.Receive(ref server_ip);
            string received_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received_bytes);
            if (received_data == "INIT")
            {
                isClietConnected = true;
                Console.WriteLine("now connected");
                listen(server_ip);
            }


        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

}
public bool sendReceiveUDP(string send){
     if(!isClientConnected){
          return false;
     }
     //perform send
     return true;
 }
```

You would then maintain the connected session using class scope and send/receive using a different method. This is for connect only since you only need to do it once.

How you set something like this up:

```
  private bool isConnected = false();
  private bool send(){
      if(!isConnected){
           connect();
      }
      //send
  }
  private bool connect(){
      if(!isConnected){
          //launch connection thread
      }
   }
  private delegate void onNewReceive(string message);
  public event onNewReceive onNewReceiveEvent;
  public void fireEvent(string message){
         onNewReceiveEvent.Invoke(message);
  }
       private void waitForData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){
     //this is the backgroundworker
     while(true){
     receive();
     fireEvent(message);
     }
  }
```

Then, subscribe to the onNewREceivedEvent in another class and process the inbound message. onNewReceivedEvent += processInboundMEsasage();

This is all psuedocode and "brain compiled" (creit to others) so it's only meant for demonstrations. Without intellisense, I'm lost.

Comment: I'm missing how this loops...?

Comment: You don't need to loop. Receive will block until it gets something. If you want to SEND something on a loop, then you need to do it in another method. Once you call receive(), the thread will stop (block) until it gets something. It will wait forever. That's why it neds to be on another thread. As soon as it completes its duty (receives something), the thread will continue along after receive() as though it's only been a microsecond even if its been four hours